# How to predict edges in the social network?

Tags: machine-learning, prediction

I need to make a recommendation system that would predict friends for users in the social graph. The number of users is around 1.500.000. I thought of creating all possible pairs of users and then calculate such metrics as jaccard distance for each pair but doing it for the matrix 1.500.000*1.500.000 seems to be an impossible task. What approaches exist to handle such an amount of nodes?